# Bootstrap Carousel Slider - CSS & JS not working

Tags: jquery

i think css or js file not load how can i solve it.
[image: Screenshoot]

functions.php here.

```
function pp_scripts() {
// Registering Bootstrap style
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
//Registering Bootstrap Script
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pp_scripts' );

add_action( 'init', 'custom_bootstrap_slider' );
/**
 * Register a Custom post type for.
 */
function custom_bootstrap_slider() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Slider', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Slide', 'post type singular name'),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Bootstrap Slider', 'admin menu'),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Slide', 'add new on admin bar'),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Slide'),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Name'),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Slide'),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Slide'),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Slide'),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Slide'),
        'featured_image'     => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Slide'),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Slide:'),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Slide found.'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Slide found in Trash.'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'menu_icon'      => 'dashicons-star-half',
                'description'        => __( 'Description.'),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
    );

    register_post_type( 'slider', $args );
}
```

for template file

```
<?php  $slider = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'slider', 'posts_per_page'   => 5)); ?>

<?php div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php $slider = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'slider', 'posts_per_page' => 5)); ?>
      <?php $count = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach($slider as $slide): ?>
      <div class="item <?php echo ($count == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($slide->ID)) ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>?>
```

Comment: How does the bootstrap carousels work? I mean, are they supposed to auto init themselved? Or do you need to add your own jquery / js function to init them? And have you inspected your sites source code to check if the files are getting enqueued?

Comment: Why function through action? Why don't you simply enqueue them with dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
// Registering Bootstrap style
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

To this:

```
// Registering Bootstrap style
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_min', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```